# How to redirect a specific dynamic page to homepage

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I can't figure out how to redirect a specific dynamic page to the homepage.

In my .htaccess file I used this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=site&cmd=blog-yyy-zzz$ [NC]
RewriteRule http://www.xxx.it/index.php http://www.xxx.it/? [R=301,L]
```

The problem is when I open `http://www.xxx.it/index.php?p=site&cmd=blog-yyy-zzz` it doesn't redirect to `http://www.xxx.it/` (I can't post more than 2 links)

Please can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant match domain name in `RewriteRule`. Use this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=site&cmd=blog-yyy-zzz$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ /? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you, but it still doesn't function.

Comment: Is this URL not redirecting: `http://www.xxx.it/index.php?p=site&cmd=blog-yyy-zzz`? Make sure above rule is **very first** rule in root .htaccess

Comment: You're right! If I open http://www.xxx.it/index.php?p=site&cmd=blog-yyy-zzz it redirects correctly. I just noticed I was making my test from the SERP of Google, where the page is indexed as www.xxx.it/?p=site&cmd=blog-yyy-zzz...without "index.php"

Comment: Made a change in rule, it will now support both forms of the URLs.